# Java Microbenchmark for IO and NIO file size method for 10k files

Tags: java, performance, jmh

I need to calculate the performance of Java IO and NIO file size and modified time api using JMH for at least 10 k files. I need code for this problem .
please guide how to write it.

My sample code for one file as below :

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class MyBenchmark
{
   public String path = new String("/home/demo.txt");

    @Benchmark
     public File baseline()
     {
       return new File(path);
     }


// @Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
   @Benchmark
   public long getFileSize()
   {
      return new File(path).length();
   }

   @Benchmark
   public  long getFileSize_NIO1() 
   {
      try
      {
         return Files.size(FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(path));
      }
      catch (IOException e)
      { }
      return 0;
   } 


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want an answer, please clarify what you exactly expect from the SO community. And show us what you tried and/or explain the problem that you face

Comment: Added the details

Comment: You do realize that a `File`'s `.length()` method is useless if the denoted path is not a directory, right? Don't use `File` in 2016 anyway.

Comment: I need to comapre IO and NIO  and path is file always not the directory here, so I have to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to test the files individually, it could be done using the annotation `@Param` as next:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class BenchmarkFileSize {

    @Param("path")
    public String path;

    @Benchmark
    public long io() {
        return new File(path).length();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public  long nio() throws IOException {
        return Files.size(Paths.get(path));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        String[] paths = buildPaths();
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(BenchmarkFileSize.class.getSimpleName())
            .param("path", paths)
            .forks(1)
            .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    private static String[] buildPaths() {
        // Here the code to build the array of paths to test
    }
}
```

If you want to tests the files all together, you will need initialize the paths to test with an init method annotated with `@Setup` as next:

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class BenchmarkFileSize {

    private List<String> paths;

    @Benchmark
    public long io() {
        long total = 0L;
        for (String path : paths) {
            total += new File(path).length();
        }
        return total;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public  long nio() throws IOException {
        long total = 0L;
        for (String path : paths) {
            total += Files.size(Paths.get(path));
        }
        return total;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(BenchmarkFileSize.class.getSimpleName())
            .forks(1)
            .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Setup
    public void buildPaths() {
        // Here the code to build the list of paths to test and affect it to paths
    }
}
```

**NB:** As you have a lot of files to test make sure that you allocate enough memory to your JVM otherwise you will get false results due to GC activity or worse OOME

Comment: Thanks a lot for great explanation Nicolas I wanted to no one thing public  long nio()  should handle exception or should throws it ? as if we have throws at function declaration, it will change declaration in case of nio,  can it causes any issue in results ?

Comment: you need to throw the exception in order to affect the error rate of your results because it is important too when you need to make a choice if you have something faster but with a much higher error rate, it could not be interesting enough